# C# interface for persisting models

Tags: c#

I have around 10 model class and I want to persist & create them to files, I want to create an interface for this. How should my interface look like?

PS: I don't want to create an instance of the model before loading the data from file, so the approach should do both create instance and load together.

Comment: What did you try for the moment ? Are you looking for a noSQL database ?

Comment: Any requirements regarding the serialization format? From the information you provided it seems best if you read some tutorial on .NET serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create interface for saving/reading you may want something like this:

```
public interface IModel { 
  int Id { get; } 
}

public interface IModelRepository {
  void Save<T>(T model) where T : IModel;
  T Load<T>(int id) where T : IModel;
}
```

Implementation must decide how to load model of type `T`, and if you have many models of type `T` saved - to which of them to load (we use `id` for that).

Please provide more information e.g. if you are working with DB or with just XML/text files in some directory.